# jxbrowser : scrollbar scrolling not right direction

Tags: scroll, scrollbar, jxbrowser

I used JXbrowser in Java App project , table will displayed in jxBrowser  in JPanel.Scrollbar of jxBrowser will showed when table have big data .When I run this project with my Laptop (have touch screen,Window 10),I touch in scrollbar and wipe down I can see bottom of table ,wide up I can see the top,everything is right,I cannot touch in table to wide down or up.But when I run this project in other device (have touch screen,Window 10), touch in scrollbar and wipe down I see the top of table ,wipe up I see the bottom, and I can touch in table to wide down or up.

Anybody help me about this? it's so strange.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot will help?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't put JxBrowser BrowserView into Java Swing scroll pane. The BrowserView has its own scroll bars that will be displayed automatically when it's necessary (like in Google Chrome). Maybe the behavior you see is causes by using two scroll panes: yours and BrowserView's.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, first of all ,thanks for your advise . But in View , I add BrowserView in Box,and Box in JPanel.I don't use JScrollpane.

Comment: Maybe this is how scroll direction is configured in your Windows 10 environment? Could you please check whether you see the same behavior in Google Chrome in the same environment.

Comment: I checked same behavior in Google Chrome in the same environment and touch run right